# Mirth & Mysql [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)]

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, sqlcipher, mirth

Im having mirth installed in an Ec2 linux instance and my mysql is placed in another Ec2 instance. In mirth.properties I have made the configuration url for mysql.

When the service is started, it stops automatically with this error message registered in the log

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:361)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1452)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:428)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:316)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:352)
        ... 44 more
```

Now i understand that certain cipher protocols used in mirth might not be compatible to mysql. So, I tried `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tls_version';` in DB and the results are `TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` I enabled only them on the mirth.properties and tried but it did not work.

**Mirth.properties cipher suits**
[image]

Mysql Version - `5.7.35` Mirth version - `3.9.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the connection string to:

```
database.url = jdbc:mysql://yourip:3306/yourmirthdb?useSSL=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

or upgrade from java 8, e.g. to v13

Comment: life saving answer !!

Comment: You sir are a hero. Worked like a charm. Thank you.